# Keycloak set value Claim value to "hardcoded claim"

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have created custom protocol mapper with mapper type "hardcoded claim".
Can I set "Claim value" field using keycloak API?
I learned API specification and did not found anything.
Is there a working example?
I am using Springboot restAPI and Keycloak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can use the endpoint [Update the mapper](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html) :

```
PUT /{realm}/clients/<ID_OF_CLIENT>/protocol-mappers/models/<ROLE_MAPPER_ID>
```

for example

```
curl -X PUT http://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/admin/realms/<REALM_NAME>/clients/<ID_OF_CLIENT>/protocol-mappers/models/<MAPPER_ID>
```

With the payload being the new updated configuration of your Mapper, for instance:

```
{"id":"<MAPPER_ID>","name":"Hardcore","protocol":"openid-connect","protocolMapper":"oidc-hardcoded-claim-mapper","consentRequired":false,"config":{"claim.value":"<NEW_HARDCODE_VALUE>","userinfo.token.claim":"true","id.token.claim":"true","access.token.claim":"true","claim.name":"Name","jsonType.label":"String"}}
```

The `ID` of Client you can get it via the Admin Console, by going to:

- your `Realm`;
- clients;
- your client;
- copy the id from the url (*e.g.,* .../clients/**10000d0a-aa00-00aa-00a0-aa0000000000**).

The mapper `ID` you can get it via the Admin console, by going to:

- your `Realm`;
- clients;
- your client;
- Mappers;
- click on your mapper;
- the ID will be on the url (*e.g.,* ../mappers/**10000d0a-aa00-00aa-00a0-aa0000000000**)

You can get both the `ID` of the Client and the Mapper by using this endpoint:

```
http://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/admin/realms/<REALM_NAME>/clients?clientId=<CLIENT_ID>
```

Extract from the `JSON` response that you will get the Client and Mapper IDs.